# What exactly is free incoming calls per second billing?

Tags: iphone, call

I'm using iPhone Lite and was wondering:

What exactly is free incoming calls per second billing?

Is it the same as free incoming calls?

And do I only have 3 free month caller number display?

Comment: Can you give more information about "iPhone Lite"? Is it an app? I'm having trouble finding why it should belong on this site. ("iPhone Lite" only yield new iPhones rumors on Google)

Comment: This sounds exactly like [M1's iPhone lite plan](http://www.m1.com.sg/iPhone/plans.html), in which is coincidentally my carrier too.

Comment: @Loic Wolff its the iphone lite plan

Comment: OK, thanks. But still, even if it's a iPhone-related phone plan, it has nothing to do on this site since it's about a phone provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Free incoming calls - you receive calls for free
2. Per Second Billing - your calls are timed per second, not per blocks (etc. 5 seconds per x cents), and is for outgoing calls (when you call people, not when people call you)
3. 3 month free caller number display - you get to see the number of the person calling you for 3 months